# Looking for a proof of two combinatorial summation identities

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

While working on a problem I came across the following similar combinatorial identities valid by numerical evidence $(n\ge m)$:
$$\begin{align}
A(n,m)&\equiv\sum_{k\ge1}\binom km\binom{n-1}{k-1}=2^{n-m-1}\binom nm\frac{n+m}{n},\\
B(n,m)&\equiv\sum_{k\ge1}\left[\binom{\left\lfloor\frac k2\right\rfloor}m
+\binom{\left\lceil\frac k2\right\rceil}m\right]\binom{n-1}{k-1}=2^{n-2m}\binom {n-m}{m-1}\frac{n+1}{m}.
\end{align}$$

I am looking for an algebraic proof of these identities.

Is there a smart way to prove:
$$
B(n,m)=A(n-m+1,m)
$$
without explicit evaluation of the sums?

Comment: The first equation: When $m=n,$ the right side is $n$ and the left side is $1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for catching the typo. Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second identity we get for the LHS

$$\sum_{k\ge 1}
\left[ {\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor \choose m} +
{\lceil \frac{k}{2} \rceil \choose m} \right]
{n-1\choose k-1}
\\ = 2\sum_{k\ge 0} {k\choose m} {n-1\choose 2k-1}
+ \sum_{k\ge 0} {k\choose m} {n-1\choose 2k}
+ \sum_{k\ge 0} {k+1\choose m} {n-1\choose 2k}$$

which we seek to prove is equal to

$$2^{n-2m} {n-m\choose m-1} \frac{n+1}{m}.$$

where we will take $m\ge 1.$ We get for the first term

$$2\sum_{k\ge 0} {k\choose m} {n-1\choose n-2k}
= 2[z^n] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{k\ge 0} {k\choose m} z^{2k}
\\ = 2[z^n] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} z^{2k}
= 2[z^{n-2m}] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{k\ge 0} {k+m\choose m} z^{2k}
\\ = 2[z^{n-2m}] (1+z)^{n-1} \frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{m+1}}.$$

The second term is

$$\sum_{k\ge 0} {k\choose m} {n-1\choose n-1-2k}
= [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{k\ge 0} {k\choose m} z^{2k}
\\ = [z^{n-2m-1}] (1+z)^{n-1} \frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{m+1}}.$$

The third term is

$$\sum_{k\ge 0} {k+1\choose m} {n-1\choose n-1-2k}
= [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{k\ge 0} {k+1\choose m} z^{2k}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{k\ge m-1} {k+1\choose m} z^{2k}
= [z^{n-2m+1}] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{k\ge 0} {k+m\choose m} z^{2k}
\\ = [z^{n-2m+1}] (1+z)^{n-1} \frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{m+1}}.$$

Adding these together we get

$$[z^{n-2m+1}] (1+z^2+2z) (1+z)^{n-1} \frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{m+1}}
= [z^{n-2m+1}] (1+z)^{n+1} \frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{m+1}}
\\ = [z^{n-2m+1}] (1+z)^{n-m} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{m+1}}.$$

The coefficient extractor now yields

$$\sum_{q=0}^{n+1-2m} {n-m\choose q} {n+1-2m-q+m\choose m}
= \sum_{q=0}^{n+1-2m} {n-m\choose q} {n+1-m-q\choose m}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n+1-2m}
 {n-m\choose q} \frac{n+1-m-q}{m} {n-m-q\choose m-1}.$$

Now

$${n-m\choose q} {n-m-q\choose m-1}
= \frac{(n-m)!}{q! \times (m-1)! \times (n+1-2m-q)!}
\\ = {n-m\choose m-1} {n+1-2m\choose q}.$$

We get for the sum

$$\frac{1}{m} {n-m\choose m-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{n+1-2m} (n+1-m-q) {n+1-2m\choose q}
\\ = \frac{1}{m} {n-m\choose m-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{n+1-2m} (n+1-2m-q) {n+1-2m\choose q}
\\ + {n-m\choose m-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{n+1-2m} {n+1-2m\choose q}
\\ = \frac{1}{m} {n-m\choose m-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{n+1-2m} q {n+1-2m\choose q}
+ {n-m\choose m-1} 2^{n+1-2m}
\\ = \frac{n+1-2m}{m} {n-m\choose m-1}
\sum_{q=1}^{n+1-2m} {n-2m\choose q-1}
+ {n-m\choose m-1} 2^{n+1-2m}
\\ = \frac{n+1-2m}{m} {n-m\choose m-1}
2^{n-2m} + {n-m\choose m-1} 2^{n+1-2m}.$$

This simplifies to

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{n+1}{m} {n-m\choose m-1} 2^{n-2m}.}$$

**Addendum.** Following the hint by OP we can simplify the
three terms first. We get

$$2\sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} {n-1\choose 2k-1}
+ \sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} {n-1\choose 2k}
+ \sum_{k\ge m-1} {k+1\choose m} {n-1\choose 2k}
\\ = 2\sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} {n-1\choose 2k-1}
+ \sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} {n-1\choose 2k}
+ \sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} {n-1\choose 2k-2}
\\ = \sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} {n\choose 2k}
+ \sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} {n\choose 2k-1}
= \sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} {n+1\choose 2k}.$$

We then find

$$\sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} {n+1\choose n+1-2k}
= [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^{n+1} \sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} z^{2k}
\\ = [z^{n+1-2m}] (1+z)^{n+1} \sum_{k\ge 0} {k+m\choose m} z^{2k}
= [z^{n+1-2m}] (1+z)^{n+1} \frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{m+1}}.$$

From this point on the computation continues as before.

Answer (score 5):

Using a coefficient extractor Eg
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{k}{m} = [x^m]:(1+x)^k.
\end{eqnarray*}
We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k\ge1}\binom km\binom{n-1}{k-1} &=& [x^m]: \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1} (1+x)^k \\ 
&=& [x^m]:  (1+x) (2+x)^{n-1} \\ 
&=& 2^{n-1-m} \binom{n-1}{m} +2^{n-m} \binom{n-1}{m-1} \\ 
&=& 2^{n-1-m}\left( \binom{n-1}{m} +2 \binom{n-1}{m-1} \right)\\ 
&=& 2^{n-1-m} \frac{(n-1)!}{m!(n-m)!} \left( n-m+2m \right)\\ 
&=& 2^{n-1-m} \frac{(n-1)!}{m!(n-m)!} (n+m).\\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
Which is the first identity (upto a factor of $n$).

Comment: And that missing factor of $n$ is supported by numerical data. E.g., for $n=4$ and $m=2$ the OP’s lefthand side is $18$, while the OP’s righthand side is $72$.

Comment: Or just try $m=n$ which gives the left side being $1$ and the right side being $n.$

Answer (score 1):

A fairly straightforward calculation using standard identities also yields the first identity:

$$\begin{align*}
n\sum_{k\ge 1}\binom{k}m\binom{n-1}{m-1}&=\sum_kk\binom{k}m\binom{n}k\\
&=\sum_kk\binom{n}m\binom{n-m}{k-m}\\
&=\binom{n}m\sum_kk\binom{n-m}{k-m}\\
&=\binom{n}m\sum_k(k+m)\binom{n-m}k\\
&=\binom{n}m\left(\sum_kk\binom{n-m}k+m\sum_k\binom{n-m}k\right)\\
&=\binom{n}m\left((n-m)\sum_k\binom{n-m-1}{k-1}+m2^{n-m}\right)\\
&=\binom{n}m\left((n-m)2^{n-m-1}+m2^{n-m}\right)\\
&=\binom{n}m(n+m)2^{n-m-1}\\
&=2^{n-m}\binom{n}m\frac{n+m}2
\end{align*}$$

For the second identity observe first that

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_k\binom{n}{2k}\binom{k}m&=\sum_k\left(\binom{n-1}{2k-1}+\binom{n-1}{2k}\right)\binom{k}m\\
&=\sum_k\binom{n-1}{2k-1}\binom{k}m+\sum_k\binom{n-1}{2k}\binom{k}m\\
&=\sum_\ell\binom{n-1}\ell\binom{\lfloor(\ell+1)/2\rfloor}m
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_k\binom{n}{2k-1}\binom{k}m&=\sum_k\left(\binom{n-1}{2k-1}+\binom{n-1}{2k-2}\right)\binom{k}m\\
&=\sum_k\binom{n-1}{2k-1}\binom{k}m+\sum_k\binom{n-1}{2k-2}\binom{k}m\\
&=\sum_\ell\binom{n-1}\ell\binom{\lceil(\ell+1)/2\rceil}m\,,
\end{align*}$$

so that

$$\begin{align*}
&\sum_k\binom{n-1}k\left[\binom{\lfloor(k+1)/2\rfloor}m+\binom{\lceil(k+1)/2\rceil}m\right]\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}m\left[\binom{n}{2k}+\binom{n}{2k-1}\right]\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}m\binom{n+1}{2k}\\
&\qquad=\frac{n+1}{2m}\sum_k\binom{k-1}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k-1}\\
&\qquad=\frac{n+1}{2m}\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}\,,
\end{align*}$$

and the problem reduces to showing that

$$\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}=2^{n-2m+1}\binom{n-m}{m-1}\,.$$

This can be proved by a double induction, the outer induction on $m$ and the inner induction on $n$. We may as well assume that $n\ge 2m-1$, as otherwise both sides are $0$.

For $n\ge m=1$ we have

$$\sum_k\binom{k}0\binom{n}{2k+1}=\sum_k\binom{n}{2k+1}=2^{n-1}=2^{n-2+1}\binom{n-1}0\,.$$

Now suppose that

$$\sum_k\binom{k}{m'-1}\binom{n'}{2k+1}=2^{n'-2m'+1}\binom{n'-m'}{m'-1}\tag{1}$$

whenever $n'\ge 2m'-1$ and $1\le m'<m$. Then the only non-zero term in

$$\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{2m-1}{2k+1}$$

is

$$\binom{m-1}{m-1}\binom{2m-1}{2(m-1)+1}=1\,,$$

and

$$2^{(2m-1)-2m+1}\binom{(2m-1)-m}{m-1}=1\,,$$

so $(1)$ holds for $m'=m$ and $n'=2m-1$. Suppose that $(1)$ holds whenever $1\le m'<m$ and $n'\ge 2m'-1$, or $m'=m$ and $2m-1\le n'\le n$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
&2^{(n+1)-2m+1}\binom{n+1-m}{m-1}\\
&\qquad=2^{n-2m+2}\left[\binom{n-m}{m-1}+\binom{n-m}{m-2}\right]\\
&\qquad=2\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad\qquad+2^{n-2m+2}\binom{(n-1)-(m-1)}{(m-1)-1}\\
&\qquad=2\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-2}\binom{n-1}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\left[\binom{n-1}{2k}+\binom{n-1}{2k+1}\right]\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-2}\binom{n-1}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n-1}{2k}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n-1}{2k+1}+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-2}\binom{n-1}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n-1}{2k}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_k\left[\binom{k}{m-1}+\binom{k}{m-2}\right]\binom{n-1}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n-1}{2k}+\sum_k\binom{k+1}{m-1}\binom{n-1}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n-1}{2k}+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n-1}{2k-1}\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\left[\binom{n-1}{2k}+\binom{n-1}{2k-1}\right]\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}+\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n}{2k}\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\left[\binom{n}{2k+1}+\binom{n}{2k}\right]\\
&\qquad=\sum_k\binom{k}{m-1}\binom{n+1}{2k+1}\,,
\end{align*}$$

so $(1)$ holds for $m'=m$ and $n'=n+1$ and by induction whenever $m'\le 1$ and $n'\ge 2m'-1$. This completes the proof of the second identity.